# Updating Multiselect Picklist based on the value of another multi picklist

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, multi-select

There are two multiselect picklist values in our org.Say, SalesOrg and Division.I want to update the first value of division picklist based on the first value of salesorg picklist.Is it possible to auto update that way using process builder,workflow or trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can update the Second Multi Pick list Values based on First Multi Pick list Value using [Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/business_process_automation/process_builder).

Step 1 : Set the condition based on the Value from Multi pick list One

[image]

Step 2: Use the Update Records action and set the Second Multi Pick list Values

[image]